# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" while using vuelidate with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I setup vuelidate in my vue typescript project like this

main.ts

```
import Vuelidate from "vuelidate";

Vue.use(Vuelidate);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Inside one of my components, I am trying to add validations for a field. This is how my component looks:

Quantity.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row align="center" justify="space-around">
      <v-col cols="1">
        <v-text-field
          v-model="quantity"
          label="qty"
          outlined
          @change="saveValue"
          :error-messages="quantityErrors"
          @input="$v.quantity.$touch()"
          @blur="$v.quantity.$touch()"
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>

...

<script>
import { required } from "@vuelidate/validators";
import { validationMixin } from "vuelidate";

...

export default {
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      quantity: null,
    }
  },
  methods:{
    saveValue(){
      console.log('saving..
    }
  },
  computed: {
    quantityErrors() {
      const errors = [];
      if (!this.$v.quantity.$dirty) return errors;
      !this.$v.quantity.required && errors.push("Qty is required");
      return errors;
    },
  validations() {
    return {
      quantity: { required },
    };
  },

...
```

But everytime i load my component, this error gets thrown

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:619 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

found in

---> <VTextField>
       <Quantity> at src/components/add/Quantity.vue
         <QuantityList> at src/components/add/QuantityList.vue
           <VForm>
             <Add> at src/views/Add.vue
               <VMain>
                 <VApp>
                   <App> at src/App.vue
                     <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js:619
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1884
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1879
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1839
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1862
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2179
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1854
Vue.$emit @ vue.runtime.esm.js:3888
(anonymous) @ VTextField.ts:442
(anonymous) @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1980
flushCallbacks @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1906
Promise.then (async)
timerFunc @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1933
nextTick @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1990
queueWatcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js:4402
update @ vue.runtime.esm.js:4544
notify @ vue.runtime.esm.js:730
reactiveSetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1055
proxySetter @ vue.runtime.esm.js:4631
onBlur @ VTextField.ts:441
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1854
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2179
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js:6917
vue.runtime.esm.js:1888 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at new Observer (vue.runtime.esm.js:911)
    at observe (vue.runtime.esm.js:988)
    at initData (vue.runtime.esm.js:4741)
    at initState (vue.runtime.esm.js:4642)
    at VueComponent.Vue._init (vue.runtime.esm.js:5006)
    at new VueComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:5154)
    at createVm (vval.js:23)
    at addVvals (vval.js:113)
    at patchChildren (vval.js:141)
    at VueComponent.refs (index.js:223)
```

Even if I remove the `:error-messages="quantityErrors"` line, and try adding a value inside the text field, the `@vblur="$v.quantity.$touch()"` gets executed and the same error gets thrown.

Any idea what I am missing ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. saveValue affects the form but it was omitted. Without `:error-messages="quantityErrors"`, I don't see how infinite loop is related to validation.

Comment: Maybe it's related to either of these?: `@input="$v.quantity.$touch()"` `@blur="$v.quantity.$touch()"`

Comment: @EstusFlask, sorry about that. I just updated saveValue. Its not doing anything right now, but just console logging. If I remove `:error-messages="quantityErrors"` i dont see an infinite loop. @gytis-tg , I removed those 2 elements and I still see the issue happening because of `:error-messages="quantityErrors"` it stops. But they independently are also contributing to the error (I add a value to the text box, the @blur gets triggered and I see the issue all over again.

Comment: Don't execute the function when the component is loaded, you just pass the function as a reference, so it should be `@input="$v.quantity.$touch"` (notice that the parentheses are removed). Regarding the import of the rule, it should be from vuelidate lib - `import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators"` (refer to official documentation - https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-basic-form)

Answer (score -1):

For me, cause of the problem was that I defined my validation rules as Strings instead of Objects.

Wrong:

```
const rules = { firstName: 'required' }
```

Right:

```
const rules = { firstName: { required } }
```

Comment: This doesn't relate as answer to the question above.